# Exception when instantiating CommonsHttpSolrServer

Tags: java, maven, solr, solrj

I have a class like this (it's a java class in eclipse, under a Maven project):

```
public class SolrJ
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
        try {
            SolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(url);
            server.deleteByQuery( "*:*" );
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SolrServerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After running this class I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.staticInitialize(LoggerFactory.java:83)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.<clinit>(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:77)
    at ultimo.solrJ.SolrJ.main(SolrJ.java:19)
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone help with my issue please? I've serached through Internet and I cannot find any method to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the docs?
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_0/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CommonsHttpSolrServer.html
Follow the suggested route

Comment: I've tried it, but when I change the CommonsHttpSolrServer onto HttpSolrServer then I have an error that there is no such class. I've tried to import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer but there is no such class in my project.

Comment: Yes, it means that you will have to download and include it in your project. If anybody (assuming that there are other people involved) complains point out that the CommonsHttpSolrServer is deprecated and therefore any development on it is highly inadvisable.

Comment: Ok, that was the problem with old version of solrj in my pom.xml. Problem solved.